# How to write all files Contain in the subfolders and in the folders in to a .txt file

Tags: c#

the following code is reading all files Contain in the subfolders and in the folders.
But  I need to write all files Contain in the subfolders and in the folders in to .txt file.
Can  any one  say  me  how do change it .

```
private void btnSearchNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BLSecurityFinder lSecFinder = new BLSecurityFinderClass();
    int iCounter = 0;

    lbselected.Items.Clear();

    lSecFinder.bScanSubDirectories = chkSubfolders.Checked;

    try
    {
        lSecFinder.FindSecurity(txtSymbol.Text, txtDirectory.Text);
        while (lSecFinder.bSecLeft)
        {
            // Insert(iCounter, lSecFinder.SecName);

            lbselected.Items.Add(new SampleData() { Name = lSecFinder.SecName });
            lbselected.DisplayMember = "Name";
            lSecFinder.FindNextSecurity();

            iCounter++;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ComEx)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show (ComEx.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        lSecFinder.DestroySearchDialog();
    }
}



   private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

thanks in  addvance

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=C%23%20write%20text%20file

Answer (score 3):

```
var searchPattern = "*.*";
var output = @"c:\results.txt";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,
    searchPattern,
    chkSubfolders.Checked ? SearchOption.AllDirectories:SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
File.WriteAllLines(output, files);
```

Comment: i am getting an error the error is highlighting var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories); and  the error is Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: searchPattern please help

Comment: Well it seems that you have not set a value for searchPattern - it cannot be null.  You need to define a string containing the searchPattern before using it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.IO class library DirectoryInfo and FileInfo class and the logic goes as follows

1) Create two functions on to process directory and one to process file

2) In which directory read function reads validate if the item is file or directory

3) If the item is directory it recursively calls itself 4) If the item is file it send it to file process method for processing

```
public void fnProcessDirectory(string strPath)
{
    if (File.Exists(strPath))
    {
        fnProcessFile(strPath);
    }
    else if (Directory.Exists(strPath))
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(strPath);
        string[] subdirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(strPath);

        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            fnProcessFile(fileName);
        }

        foreach (string dirName in subdirEntries)
        {
            fnProcessDirectory(dirName);
        }
    }
}

public void fnProcessFile(string strPath)
{
    //write the file name in the txt file
}
```

Comment: call fnProcessDirectory in  btnBrowse_Click function and assign the files names into a class level variable in fnProcessFile

Comment: can u please say me how to call fnProcessDirectory in btnBrowse_Click i am new to C#

Comment: fnProcessDirectory(txtDirectory.Text);

Comment: its not working as u say i called the fnProcessDirectory in btnBrowse_Click it look like this    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {           
           folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
           if (folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath != "")
           {
               txtDirectory.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                 fnProcessDirectory(txtDirectory.Text); 
           }
       } and i did not understand how to assign the files names into a class level variable in fnProcessFile can u please add the things in my code and send it .

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the folder and sub-folder filesNames.
you can specify the type of file you looking for or * to get every file.

```
public void File_To_Text(string filepath)
{  
  string [] fname;

            fname = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
            File.WriteAllLines("c:\\images.txt", fname, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version which extends your code directly:

```
private void btnSearchNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BLSecurityFinder lSecFinder = new BLSecurityFinderClass();
    int iCounter = 0;

    lbselected.Items.Clear();

    lSecFinder.bScanSubDirectories = chkSubfolders.Checked;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\results.txt", false))
    {
        try
        {
            lSecFinder.FindSecurity(txtSymbol.Text, txtDirectory.Text);
            while (lSecFinder.bSecLeft)
            {
                // Insert(iCounter, lSecFinder.SecName);

                lbselected.Items.Add(new SampleData() { Name = lSecFinder.SecName });
                lbselected.DisplayMember = "Name";

                // assuming SecName is the full filename
                writer.WriteLine(lSecFinder.SecName); 

                lSecFinder.FindNextSecurity();

                iCounter++;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ComEx)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show (ComEx.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            lSecFinder.DestroySearchDialog();
        }
    }
}
```