# how to loop , read and write the folders and subfolders files

Tags: c#

I am having a problem writing the files in folders and subfolders .

For Example:- test is the main folder

1) C:\test\

and i want to read and write the subfolder files

2)C:\test\12-05-2011\12-05-2011.txt

3)C:\test\13-05-2011\13-05-2011.txt

4)C:\test\14-05-2011\14-05-2011.txt

My code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string Path1 = @"C:\test";
    DoOnSubfolders(Path1);

    try
    {
        StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
        string str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
        reader1.Close();
        reader1.Dispose();
        File.Delete(Path1);
        string[] Strarray = str.Split(new char[] { Strings.ChrW(10) });
        int abc = Strarray.Length - 2;
        int xyz = 0;
        while (xyz <= abc)

}
```

I am getting an error.  The error is 
Access to the path 'C:\test' is denied.

Can anyone say me what i need to change in this code?

Comment: So are you providing a list of folders or do you want it to recursively go through every subfolder of the folder you are specifying?

Comment: i want to  recursively go through every subfolder of the folder

Comment: It's not clear from your code where you're writing out any information - given this is what's failing, that's a rather important part.

Comment: You dont seem to have any code in there to do any writing - what are you expecting it to write?

Comment: Do you tried to check your code in debuger? I think its a simple error and you easly can catch it with debugger

Comment: the error is Access to the path 'C:\test' is denied.

Comment: But for future you have to configure security on the `c:\Test` folder.

Comment: to set permission follow this [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_2383435_set-permissions-windows-xp.html)

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5988132/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: I think it's obvious that the asker either doesn't speak english well or isn't a programmer - he seems to be having trouble answering simple questions about his problem.

Answer (score 3):

At first you could flatten your recursive calls by calling [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(string, SearchOption)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx) and setting the [`SearchOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx) to `AllDirectories`.

What's also a common mistake (but not clear from your question) is that a directory needs to be created, before you can create a file. Simply call [`Directory.CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory.aspx). And put in the complete path (without filename) into it. It will automatically do nothing if the directory already exists and is also able to create the whole needed structure. So no checks or recursive calls are needed (maybe a try-catch if you don't have write access).

#### Update

So here is an example that reads in a file, does some conversion on each line and writes the result into a new file. If this works properly the original file will be replaced by the converted one.

```
private static void ConvertFiles(string pathToSearchRecursive, string searchPattern)
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(pathToSearchRecursive);

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Directory doesn't exists: " + dir.ToString());
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPattern))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("searchPattern");
    }

    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

        // Use the using statement to make sure file is closed at the end or on error.
        using (var reader = file.OpenText())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
        {
            string line;

            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                var split = line.Split((char)10);
                foreach (var item in split)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }

        // Replace the original file be the converted one (if needed)
        ////File.Copy(tempFile, file.FullName, true);
    }
}
```

In your case you could call this function

```
ConvertFiles(@"D:\test", "*.*")
```

Answer (score 2):

To recursively walk the sub-folders, you need a recursive function ie. One that calls itself. here is an example that should be enough for you to work with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string path = @"C:\temp\";
    DoOnSubfolders(path);
}

private static void DoOnSubfolders(string rootPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);
    FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (var fi in fis)
    {
        string str = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName);
        //do your stuff
    }

    DirectoryInfo[] ds = d.GetDirectories();
    foreach (var info in ds)
    {
        DoOnSubfolders(info.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: its reading but its not writing to the given path 
       const string Path1 = @"C:\test\";
       DoOnSubfolders(Path1);
          but an error occured the error is  Could not find a part of the path 'C:\test\'. can u add this code to my code            
       StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
       string str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
       reader1.Close();
       reader1.Dispose();
       File.Delete(Path1);
       string[] Strarray = str.Split(new char[] { Strings.ChrW(10) });
       int abc = Strarray.Length - 2;
       int xyz = 0;

Answer (score 1):

You need use class Directory info and FileInfo.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\test");
FileInfo [] fis = d.GetFiles();
DirectoryInfo [] ds = d.GetDirectories();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick one liner to write the contents of all text files in a given directory (and all subdirectories) to the console:

```
Directory.GetFiles(myDirectory,"*.txt*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(a)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
const string Path1 = @"C:\test";  
StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
```

Says open "c:\test" as a text file...  The error you're getting is:

```
Access to the path 'C:\test' is denied
```

You're getting the error because as you stated above, 'c:\test' is a folder.  You can't open folders like they are text files, hence the error...

A basic (full depth search) for files with a `.txt` extension looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    ProcessDir(@"c:\test");
}


static void ProcessDir(string currentPath) {
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(currentPath, "*.txt")) {

        // Process each file (replace this with your code / function call /
        // change signature to allow a delegate to be passed in... etc
        // StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(file);  // etc

        Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", file);
    }

    // recurse (may not be necessary), call each subfolder to see 
    // if there's more hiding below
    foreach (var subFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(currentPath)) {
        ProcessDir(subFolder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974 for a start.  The secret is Directory.GetDirectories in System.IO.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure (NTFS) security on the c:\Test folder.

Normally you would have the application run under non-admininstrator account so the account that is running the program should have access.

If you are running on Vista or Windows 7 with UAC, you might be an administrator but you will not be using the administrative (elevated) permissions by default.

**EDIT**

Look at these lines:

```
const string Path1 = @"C:\test";
DoOnSubfolders(Path1);
try
{
    StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
```

That last line is trying to read the **FOLDER** 'c:\test' as if it was a text file.

You can't do that. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: I am using XP3 how to run as a administrator

Comment: Can you pin down the line that is causing the exception?

Comment: catch (Exception)
                {
                    //in this the error is Access to the path 'C:\test' is denied.
                }

Comment: this is the catch, NOT the line that is causing the exception.

Comment: StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1); this is the line which is giving error

Comment: You are trying to read a folder as if it were a file. That is causing the exception.

Comment: See the edit of my answer. Please explain what you are trying to do in the line that is causing the exception.

Comment: i want to read and write the files and subfolders because there are many text files which is of different date which is stored in subfolders i want to read and write the files by giving the main folder is any other way to read and write the files contain in the subfolders

Comment: But why are you reading the FOLDER as a file? I answered a previous question of you that shows how to read all files in all sub folders. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946503/how-to-write-all-files-contain-in-the-subfolders-and-in-the-folders-in-to-a-txt